# Other manufacturer's USB data cable for charging?

Tags: usb, charging

Is there any harm in using a USB data cable of any other phone (say LG) for charging up a Nexus S? "Any harm" here means will it adversely effect my battery life or the Nexus S device in any way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

USB data cables are pretty much interchangeable. Even on devices that have modified sockets to allow connecting a headset cable to the USB port, you can usually still use a normal USB cable for charging and data with no harm to the device.

Comment: I use an old Nokia cable on occasion with no problems.

Comment: What you might want to watch out for though are dollar-store chargers (either AC or car)... not really sure how the regulation on those is.

Comment: My HTC Desire and Kindle share the same style USB connector which is handy while traveling, I wish everyone would standardize on the same connector :)

Comment: Apple-related, but relevant to @ChrisStratton's comment: http://www.righto.com/2014/05/a-look-inside-ipad-chargers-pricey.html (related to chargers, not cables).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Nexus S uses the so called `micro-USB cable`, the same my Galaxy 5 does.

This is very good, because you can buy a generic cable like that in retail stores or shops that sells electronic stuff. I did so a few days after I bought my cell phone, and it costed the equivalent of US$4.00 in my country (Chile).