# How do I just charge (i.e. not mount for data transfer) a Galaxy Nexus when connected via USB to a PC?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, charging, usb-connection-mode

I like to be able to charge my phone from any PC I happen to be using. With my previous HTC Android, I could default to "charge-only" and only switch it to "mount as disc drive" when I wished to, on my own machines.

Why? Being prompted for driver installs (at least on a Windows machine) is annoying;  connecting a storage device to a PC I don't own may be against policy/protocol/politeness.

It would appear that the Galaxy Nexus uses two protocols, MTP and PTP; I currently have only MTP switched on, but can't turn it off.

I could try to find a ['"USB" cable that only connects pins 1 & 4 ... [to provide] ... power and no data'.](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/14596/6757). But this would mean carrying two different USB cables around.

Any other solutions?

Comment: This is a security issue also.  I want to be able to connect to untrusted computers for charging.  It seems crazy that this option available by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is called "fast charge", and it charges your device slightly faster by disabling the USB data capability. It's not available in the stock ROM that I know of, so you need a ROM and a kernel that you know supports this. I'm using AOKP with the Franco kernel and it works great on my Galaxy Nexus, so you could try that. (There's even a quick toggle for fast charge available).

There's *probably not* an unrooted solution for this.

> Being prompted for driver installs (at least on a Windows machine) is annoying

It might be good to know that installing the correct USB drivers for the Galaxy Nexus in Windows is not something that happens automatically. If you decide to root and flash your device, you'll encounter this; I highly recommend using [Galaxy Nexus Toolkit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1392310) to make the procedure as easy as possible (it's really not that hard).

Comment: I'm on CM9 with Franco and fast charge seems to work fine but I'm still promoted to install the Samsung drivers on the computers at work. Does that mean fast charge isn't working properly? It is pretty annoying to be prompted every time when in have no intention of installing the drivers on a particular computer.

Comment: I think that means it doesn't work properly, yes. The phone shouldn't make any data contact what so ever with the computer in fast charge mode.